# Making a table column Date or String based on type

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm making an SSRS Report for my accounting team and I'm hitting a wall on their custom fields requirements.

I created a custom code function for this:

```
Public Function DateOrString(ByVal s As String) As String
    Try
        Dim dt = CDate(s)

        Return dt.ToString("d")
    Catch
        Return s
    End Try
End Function
```

Which when I ran that in VS it works like it should but when I used it in my SSRS report like so:

```
=Code.DateOrString(Fields!customuserfield1.Value)
```

works, but the date field is not converting at all

I need a string that equals "May 23 2011 12:00AM" to convert to "05/23/2011"

Not sure what's the disconnect is, hoping someone can tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of desk to head beating I got a working solution.

in the stored procedure I had to do some data cleaning so that my custom code would properly work, once I did that it worked like it should have.